# Vuelidate set dirty false for all properties when form is submitted

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I have a simple Form with configured [`Vuelidate`](https://vuelidate.js.org/) validators. It shows an error messages if the `input` is in `dirty` state, so when the `form` is opened at the first time there are no errors.

But when I click `submit` I expect to get a "clear" `form`, as well as I just open it, but instead, I get all my validation errors within my `input`.

Is there any elegant way to reset all `vuelidate` fields to `clear` state again, and get `clear` form?

```js
<script>
  import {required, email} from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        email: ''
        //there could be a lot of props
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onSubmit() {
        if (!this.$v.$invalid) {
          const user = {
            email: this.email,
            //there could be a lot of props
          };

          console.log(user);

          this.email = '';
        }
      }
    },
    validations: {
      email: {required, email}
    }
  }
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <form class="form" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
      <div class="input">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input
          :class="{ error: $v.email.$error }"
          type="email"
          id="email"
          v-model.trim="email"
          @input="$v.email.$touch()">
        <div v-if="$v.email.$dirty">
          <p class="error-message" v-if="!$v.email.email">Please enter a valid email</p>
          <p class="error-message" v-if="!$v.email.required">Email must not be empty</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button :disabled="$v.$invalid" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

after some research I found that `this.$v.$reset();` makes things